# MySql concurrency with COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, concurrency

I Have a table with user_id and product_id.

For my purpose, a particular user is allowed up to 5 rows only.

To enforce this, I created such a SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO the_table (product_id, user_id) 
SELECT p, u FROM (SELECT 121 AS p, 40987 AS u)  
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_table WHERE user_id = 40987) < 5;
```

#### Now My Question:

without explicit locking\transaction,
Is in the case of two simultaneous command run,
When the number of rows before their run is 4,
It is possible that the count will be calculated for both commands before making the insertion - Then there will be 6 rows for same user_id?

Comment: *For my purpose, a particular user is allowed up to 5 rows only.* If so, I recommend create 5 records (with NULLs in data fields) for each user when the user is created, and use only `UPDATE .. WHERE somefield IS NULL`, not INSERT. This method allows to update (fill with data) records 5 times only. And no interference because no subqueries.

Comment: `SELECT p, u FROM (SELECT 121 AS p, 40987 AS u) WHERE ...` can be simplified (ie, sped up) to `SELECT 121, 40987 FROM DUAL WHERE ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is sometimes needed, I think you must implement your action in a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_table WHERE user_id = 40987 FOR UPDATE;
if the count >= 5, ROLLBACK and exit.
INSERT INTO the_table (product_id, user_id) VALUES (121, 40987);
COMMIT;
```

Or...

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO the_table (product_id, user_id) VALUES (121, 40987);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_table WHERE user_id = 40987;
if the count > 5, ROLLBACK and exit.
COMMIT;
```

(Three diffs:  order of statements; `FOR UPDATE`; `>=` vs `>`.)

In your original code, see if you can add `FOR UPDATE` to the subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank! but without `for update` and transaction, what's happening?

Comment: and, with `for update` without `begin...commit`?

Comment: @dovid - I think that the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is always in a transaction, then end of which releases the locks.  `autocommit=OFF` --> end of the statement.  `autocommit=ON` --> the transaction continues until `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but unlikely without millisecond timing. If it CANNOT happen, put it in a transaction.

Comment: Could you add some facts and reference material to support your theory? Your current answer is a bit short and lacks some form of proof.

Comment: *Possible* I think that's not right. Query is an atom. Try parallel execution of a lot of queries like `INSERT INTO table (field) SELECT value WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table, (SELECT SLEEP(pause)) dummy ) < amount;`